# cannot start docker daemon in openSUSE

Tags: opensuse, docker, suse

I'm running openSUSE, and when I try to start the docker daemon `sudo service docker start` I get the following error:

`Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.28/version: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied`

I've installed docker through zypper

#### os info:

`NAME="openSUSE Tumbleweed"
VERSION="20170725"
ID=opensuse
ID_LIKE="suse"
VERSION_ID="20170725"
PRETTY_NAME="openSUSE Tumbleweed"
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:opensuse:tumbleweed:20170725"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.opensuse.org"
HOME_URL="https://www.opensuse.org/"`

#### docker version

`Client:
 Version:      17.04.0-ce
 API version:  1.28
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   78d1802
 Built:        Tue Jul  4 16:31:44 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by simple adding my user to the docker group `sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER` and after that I reboot my machine `sudo shutdown -r now` and everything goes ok

Answer (score 2):

I also go that error on openSUSE when trying to use `docker start` and `docker run`. However, if I use this command it starts fine:

`systemctl start docker --`

As far as I know, that is the recommended way to start docker on openSUSE.